# Set and return optional property in single match statement

Tags: rust

I have the following code which does two things :

1. sets an optional property if it is not set
2. gets [a borrowed reference to] the value of the property (which should be set)

This is the code :

```
struct Object {
    property: Option<String>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut object = Object { property : None };

    /* other code */

    match object.property {
        None => {
            object.property = Some(String::from("Hello"));
        },
        Some(_) => (),
    };

    let property = match &object.property {
        None => panic!("property should be set"),
        Some(property) => property,
    }

    /* other code */
}
```

I am trying to combine these two steps into one, but I am running into moved values and lifetime issues.

```
let property = match object.property {
     None => {
         let property = String::from("Hello");
         object.property = Some(property);       //<-- property is moved into the Option struct
         &property                               //<-- issue
     },
     Some(property) => &property,
 };
```

Is there a correct way to rewrite this code such that it compiles, I guess by letting the compiler know that the lifetime of `property` will last as long as the lifetime of `object` ?

Comment: I think the application to your problem would be `let property = object.property.get_or_insert_with(|| String::from("Hello"));`

Comment: Or simply `let property = object.property.get_or_insert(String::from("Hello"));`; or if you only need reference, not the mutable one, `let property = &object.property.unwrap_or(String::from("Hello"));`.